# Returning reference to parent class C++

Tags: c++

I've been experimenting with a tuple-like data structure. It should contain only 1 of each type of object, and each object should be a c-style PODS. It uses a bizarre way of accessing the objects it holds, where it returns a reference to a class it derives from. Like:

```
template<class... Ts>
class Container : private Ts... 
{
public:
    template<class T>
    T& get_component() 
    {   //returns reference to base class specified by T
        return static_cast<T&>(* const_cast<Container<Ts...> *>(this));
    }
};
```

And the intended to be used like this:

```
struct A { int   x, y; };
struct B { float x, y; };

int main() 
{
    using namespace std;

    Container<A, B> foo;
    A& a_ref = foo.get_component<A>();

    a_ref.x = 5;
    a_ref.y = 10;

    const B& b_ref = foo.get_component<B>();

    cout << b_ref.x << endl;
    cout << b_ref.y << endl;
}
```

The method I use has to const_cast this, then dereference it, than static_casts it to T&. Are there any pitfalls in the technique I'm using? In the tests I've ran this design seems to perform as expected.

Edit:
The const_cast is redundant. I had a misconception of assigning a reference to the this pointer. I should just be static_casting T& to a dereferenced this.

Comment: Why are you using the `const_cast` in the first place? You're just casting to the same type.

Comment: If you want to add `const`, you can use `static_cast`

Comment: @krzaq Or you just change the return type to `const T&` and make the function `const`, too

Comment: You're correct, there is no reason for me to be const_casting. I had a misconception of assigning references to this.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell this can be simplified to just:

```
template<class... Ts>
class Container : private Ts... 
{
public:
    template<class T>
    T& get_component() 
    {
        return *this;
    }

    template<class T>
    const T& get_component() const
    {
        return *this;
    }
};
```

If you are allowed to retrieve the components I am questioning why they are private base classes.

One possible problem with the code is multiple occurences of the same base type, e.g.:

```
struct A {};
struct B : A {};

Container<A,B> container;
auto& a_ref = container.get_component<A>();
```

That gives an error. You can avoid something like this by having using private data members instead of private bases, which would only allow `get_component` to work on immediate bases.

Comment: One of the reasons is to resolve ambiguities, saying foo.x is ambiguous because both A, and B have the member x.

Comment: @Brian: If you used public bases, then you could simply use `A& a_ref = foo;` and `get_component` would be unnecessary.